# Is "着物デート" the Japanese for "kimono date", and what exactly does it mean?

Tags: meaning

I came across the English term "kimono date" (example [1](http://www.okwave.com/en/culturezine/four_panel_comic_strips/53/690/en), [2](http://crazyskies.deviantart.com/art/Day-4-On-a-Date-549760570), [3](https://kyotokimono-rental.com/en/english-blog/kamakura-kimono-date-%E2%9D%A4.html)), and I assume it's the English translation of a Japanese phrase. Is the equivalent Japanese "着物デート", and does it mean a romantic date done while wearing a kimono (or a yukata)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And does it mean a romantic date done while wearing a kimono (or a yukata)?

Yes, it's exactly as you guessed.